# Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am getting run time error: `Bad real number in item 1 of list input` for this sample problem. Please, suggest the correct way.

```
    implicit double precision (a-h,o-x)
    parameter (ni=150)  
    dimension x(ni)
    open(40,file='fortin')
    do 80 i=1,5
    read(40,*)x(i)
    write(*,*)i,x(i)
80  continue
    stop
    end
```

The data in the `fortin` file arranged in column

```
   1.0     
   5.0     
   3.0
   5.0
   7.0
```

Comment: There are no words at the top of 'fortin', (ii) read(*,*) is not reading values from the file.

Comment: i'd recommend open with status='old' in case you have a path issue and aren't even opening the file you think.

Comment: I get the exact error you mention when I have characters at the top of `fortin`. When I delete those characters (and keep the blank line), I get no errors & the data reads fine. The issue is surely your file.

Comment: Thanks Kyle Kanos, & George for the help.

Comment: Well, when I created the file afresh, the problem vanished.  It is the problem with the input file, Kyle is right!.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code expects only numbers and it appears you have characters in the file. You can do one of two things to fix this:

1. Delete the words at the top of the `fortin` file
2. Add a single `read(*,*)` (no need for anything following it) before the loop

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem lies in the data file, not the code.

My problem turn out to be the file is in Unicode format. When I view in vi, it's shown fine. But when I view in a viewer that does not support unicode, such as using midnight commander, it look like a mess. The one who sent me the file later told me that he save the file in UTF-16.